# SpringBoot: Two Login Pages with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want configure Spring Security to work with two different login pages for some pages

**The goal is:**

- /admin should use a **custom** login page
- /actuator should use the **standard** spring login page
- all other (like /api or so) are permitted **without** login

**My problem is:**

My solution does not work.

All /admin pages and the /actuator page are accessable without login

Here is my SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig {

  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class AdminAppConfiguration {

    final AdminEnvironmentProperties adminEnvironmentProperties;

    public AppConfiguration(AdminEnvironmentProperties adminEnvironmentProperties) {
      this.adminEnvironmentProperties = adminEnvironmentProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
      return new AdminLogoutSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

      authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Admin").password("changeme").authorities(this.adminEnvironmentProperties.getAllowGroup());

      return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.antMatcher("/admin*")
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
          .hasAuthority(this.adminEnvironmentProperties.getAllowGroup())
          .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/admin/login")
            .permitAll()
          .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccessHandler())
          .and()
            .csrf().disable();

      return http.build();
    }
  }

  @Configuration
  @Order(2)
  public static class OtherAppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/actuator").authenticated()
          .anyRequest().permitAll()
          .and().httpBasic();

      return http.build();
    }
  }
}
```

How can i fix that, so that all pages behind /admin get the custom login page, /actuator gets the standard login page and all others (like /api/** or so) are permitted without login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself

My mistake was to use the method name **securityFilterChain** twice.

Changing the method names from **securityFilterChain** to **admin** and **allOther** did the trick

**MY SOLUTION**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig {

  final AdminEnvironmentProperties adminEnvironmentProperties;

  public AppConfiguration(AdminEnvironmentProperties adminEnvironmentProperties) {
    this.adminEnvironmentProperties = adminEnvironmentProperties;
  }

  @Bean
  public LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
    return new AdminLogoutSuccessHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

    authenticationManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Admin").password("changeme").authorities(this.adminEnvironmentProperties.getAllowGroup());

    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public SecurityFilterChain admin(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/admin/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority(this.adminEnvironmentProperties.getAllowGroup())
          .and()
        .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/admin/login").permitAll()
          .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
          .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccessHandler());

    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain allOther(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
        .antMatcher("/**")
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/actuator").authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();

    return http.build();
  }
}
```